# Multiple methods

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having trouble figuring out why the output is all 0 instead of the respective user input. I have set every variable to static so it can be used everywhere. What I am confused about is the random 0 that comes out of nowhere.

```
static int hours,payrate,id;
static double grosspay;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void readInput(int hours,int payrate,int id,Scanner sc)
{
    if (id != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Employees id : ");
        id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number of hours worked is : ");
        hours = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The standard payrate is : ");
        payrate = sc.nextInt();
    }
    else
        return;
}

public static double computePay(int hours,double grosspay,int payrate)
{

    if(hours <= 160)
        grosspay = hours * payrate;
    else
        grosspay = 160 * payrate + (hours - 160) * 1.5 * payrate;
    return grosspay;
}

public static void Output(double grosspay,int id)
{
    System.out.println("For Employee id " + id + ", grosspay is " + grosspay);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    readInput(hours,payrate,id,sc);
    System.out.println("Grosspay is: " + computePay(hours,grosspay,payrate));
    Output(grosspay,id);
    System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: In your `readInput` method you're assigning the result to the variables passed to the method. Instance variables are *not* affected by this assignment.

Comment: Where ? With what input ? Could you explain you test and problem a bit more please.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is passing parameters to `readInput`. These parameters are local variables, which hide the static members having the same names. Therefore the static members are not updated.

Simply changing your method to :

```
public static void readInput() {
    if (id != -1) {
        System.out.println("Employees id : ");
        id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number of hours worked is : ");
        hours = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The standard payrate is : ");
        payrate = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

will solve this issue.

However, your code doesn't look good. You should prefer instance variables or local variables over static variables.

Comment: Still need a `Scanner` reference.

Comment: @MuratK. You mean `static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`?

Comment: There is already a static Scanner sc ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah nevermind. I looked into the main method.

Comment: This is a very clean answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to use `this` to refer to the actual static class variables and all will be fine:

```
public static void readInput(int hours,int payrate,int id,Scanner sc) {
    if (id != -1) {
        System.out.println("Employees id : ");
        this.id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number of hours worked is : ");
        this.hours = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The standard payrate is : ");
        this.payrate = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return;
}
```

Because the parameters in `readInput()` have the same names as the static class variables, the former variables "mask" the latter.  Hence, your assignments fall on deaf ears and do not stick.

Comment: Or just remove the parameters since they are useless anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In your `readInput` method you're assigning the result to the variables passed to the method. Instance variables are *not* affected by this assignment.

> What I am confused about is the random 0 that comes out of nowhere.

It's not random at all, this behavior is stated in the [JLS **4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), [§15.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)):
>
> - [...]
> - For type int, the **default value is zero, that is, 0**.
> - [...]

Comment: ...but the variables he intends to assign in `readInput()` are not instance variables, they are static class level variables.  But yeah I get the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The class variables are static, and they have default values.